# Pygame player position

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making a platformer in pygame and I was quite far along in the code when I changed how the levels where gonna be set up so I now needed to have the player start at the top of the screen instead of the bottom so it was simple I just needed to change the attributes witch I call into my player class so tat the position can change as that's how it was set in the first place but the player just kept starting in the same place

```
player = player(100,screen_height+100)

def tryagain(self,x,y):
    player1 = pygame.image.load('guy.png')
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player1, (40,75))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (x,y)
```

2
`class player(): def __init__(self, x, y): self.tryagain(x,y)`

```
screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

i even coded all the code from the start but now the Collisions with platforms refuse to work even thoi never chaged that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top left of the pygame coordinate system is (0, 0):

<s>`player = player(100,screen_height+100)`</s>

```py
player = player(100, 100)
```

Comment: I feel stupid now because when I first did that I didn't work but now I saw I forgot to update the class for when the player dies to reset